# How to use Transferable for Table Rows in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

With WWDC 2022, Apple introduced the [Transferable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreTransferable/Transferable?changes=_3) protocol to support Drag & Drop operations in an easy way. How can I use this new technique (in combination with the new [draggable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/draggable(_:)) and [dropDestination](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/dropdestination(for:action:istargeted:)?changes=_3) modifiers) for SwiftUI [tables](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/table) (not lists)?

The [TableRowContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablerowcontent?changes=latest_minor) does not support the `draggable` and `dropDestination` modifiers. Also, when applying the modifiers directly to the views in the `TableColumn`s, the drag / drop operation will only work on for that specific cell, and not the entire row. When adding the modifiers to all cells, it still does not work when dragging e.g. in an empty space inside of a row.

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Codable, Transferable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .text)
    }
}

struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        Table {
            TableColumn("Column 1") { item in
                Text(item.text)
                    .draggable(item) // This does only work when dragging not in the space between two columns
            }
            TableColumn("Column 2") { item in
                Text(item.text)
                    .draggable(item) // This does only work when dragging not in the space between two columns
            }
        } rows: {
            ForEach([Item(text: "Hello"), Item(text: "World")]) { item in
                TableRow(item)
                    .draggable(item) // This causes a compile-time error
                    .itemProvider { ... } // This does not work with Transferable and thus support my use case
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want a similar behavior as the [itemProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablerowcontent/itemprovider(_:)?changes=latest_minor) modifier and the recently added [contextMenu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablerowcontent/contextmenu(menuitems:preview:)?changes=latest_minor) modifier on the `TableRowContent` , which allow the respective operation on the whole table row. I cannot use `itemProvider`, since it requires to return an [NSItemProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider), which does not support my use case of dragging a file from a network drive to the Mac hard drive.

Comment: There are 2 ways to support drag and drop. 1. `NSItemProvider` and 2. `Transferable`. With Transferable, based on my testing I faced the same issue with selection (space) on List on macOS and dragging. Also I couldn't drag multiple items. I had not tested on Table. Based on your question, it seems like related. Please raise a feedback with Apple. Also execute the same code on iOS, based on my experience  on iOS things worked as expected. Seems like bug / limitation, raise a feedback with Apple.

Comment: `NSItemProvider` worked on macOS with `List`, so you could try that as a workaround. Future is `Transferable` so beware that in future it might make sense to move to `Transferable` once the APIs are fully baked for macOS

Comment: I have filed a feedback for List with Transferable. You could do even better is to ask Apple SwiftUI team on Thursday directly, there is a Q & A session

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I found a solution to use both in combination: Register the `Transferable` in a `NSItemProvider`, thus allowing to drag the table row everywhere and still use `Transferable` under the hood. Unfortunately this will instantly try to download the dragged file from my network drive instead of only when the drag operation ended. This makes it still unusable if you drag for example a large file or many files at once. Is there any way to achieve a similar behavior like file promises in AppKit?

Comment: @user1046037 Which Q&A session are you referring to? Do you have a link or something?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/events/ask-apple/ and register

Comment: You better file the feedback now with a sample project, so that you can pass on feedback ID to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that you can register a `Transferable` object in the `NSItemProvider`:

```
TableRow(item)
    .itemProvider {
        let provider = NSItemProvider()
        provider.register(item)
        return provider
    }
```

Unfortunately the `itemProvider` closure is already called when the dragging session starts instead of when the drop was performed. But I guess this problem is a different question to answer.