# How to use Transferable in an asynchronous way in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I'd like to drag a file in my application (representing a file on a network drive) to the user's Desktop or Finder window. Consequently the file should only be downloaded once the drag & drop operation ended.

Using AppKit I could achieve this behavior using [File Promises](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/supporting_drag_and_drop_through_file_promises). But for SwiftUI, there seems to be no equivalent. The only option is to use `NSItemProvider` or `Transferable` (or both in combination) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436387/how-to-use-transferable-for-table-rows-in-swiftui/74449089#74449089)). But neither `NSItemProvider` nor `Transferable` support this asynchronous behavior.

The main problem is that `itemProvider` closure and also the `FileRepresentation` closure is called when the dragging session starts, thus also starting the download of the files. This makes the feature unusable e.g. if you drag a large file or many files at once.

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Transferable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let description: String
    let url: URL

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .fileURL) { (item: DragItem) in
            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // This download is already started when the drag & drop session starts
            let (tempURL, response) = try! await urlSession.download(from: item.url)
            return SentTransferredFile(tempURL)
        }
    }
}

let items = [
    Item(name: "Name 1", description: "Description 1", url: URL(string: "https://...")),
    Item(name: "Name 2", description: "Description 2", url: URL(string: "https://...")),
    Item(name: "Name 3", description: "Description 3", url: URL(string: "https://..."))
]

struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        Table {
            TableColumn("Column 1") { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            TableColumn("Column 2") { item in
                Text(item.description)
            }
        } rows: {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                TableRow(item)
                    .itemProvider {
                        let provider = NSItemProvider()
                        provider.register(item)
                        return provider
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve such an asynchronous behavior in SwiftUI as it was possible in AppKit using `NSFilePromiseProvider` and `NSFilePromiseProviderDelegate`?